# Dalvikvm Not Found

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I am running  `/home/ubuntu/android-x86/rund.sh -cp /tmp/Foo.jar Foo`  command in terminal under `/home/ubuntu/android-x86/` directory and it works fine. But when I try it from different directory lets say from root it throws this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/android-x86/rund.sh: 20: exec: //out/host/linux-x86/bin/dalvikvm: not found
```

So,is it a must to run it under android-x86 directory? Why I need to run from different directory is that I am trying to implement this command from java code which is:

```
Process send = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/home/ubuntu/android-x86.rund.sh -cp /tmp/Foo.jar Foo"});
```

My concern is to run this command from java code which throws exception in terminal.

Comment: Have you updated your PATH variable to include also the android directory? I feel this is a scope problem..

Comment: I have done "export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/android-x86/" but still same error.

Comment: The leading `//` looks like it's prepending the cwd (which you said was "root") to the path to create a full path.  Run the script from the top directory of the source tree (the place where the "out" directory is).